# Check if SIMD machine is generated for LLVM IR

Tags: llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I have a C++ program that uses the LLVM libraries to generate an LLVM IR module and it compiles and executes it.

The code uses vector types and I want to check if it translates to SIMD instructions correctly on my architecture.

How do I find this out? Is there a way to see the assembly code that is generated out of this IR?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for some combination of -emit-llvm which outputs IR instead of native assembly, and -S which outputs assembly instead of object files.